# Display Response from POST on Page in Vue / Nuxt 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component

I'm using Nuxt.js 3 and I want to display the content of a client side POST request on my index page. When the page is hotloaded from a change I'm getting the result that I want, but when it loads fresh it'll always return an error and the text won't load in.

I've never really worked in javascript of any sort before so I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but I'm not sure what.

I've tried doing it like this:

#### my-component.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
      <h2>{{ myResponseTitle }}</h2>
      <p>{{ myResponseText }}</h2>
  </div>
</template>
<script setup>
  const { data: response } = await useFetch('http://localhost:5000/api/endpoint', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({ tz: Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone }) 
  })
  
  const myResponseTitle = response.value.title
  const myResponseText = response.value.text
</script>
```

#### index.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <client-only>
      <div>
        <my-component/>
      </div>
    </client-only>
  </div>
</template>
```

This produces an error like:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: response.value is null
>
> > setup my-component.vue:12

Ideally I'd like the page to load and then for that component to load when the request returns, but even having it block while waiting for the request would be fine.

Comment: That gets rid of the error, but the content doesn't appear on the page.

Comment: When it's set to response.title and I console.log(response) I get this:
`{
  "__v_isShallow": false,
  "__v_isRef": true,
  "_rawValue": {
    "title": "Chapter 75",
    "text": "Some long text here."
  }
}`

Comment: You might be returning some null data from nuxt.js. You can handle null values by using the optional chaining operator in javascript. Use `response.value?.title`

Comment: Interesting, so using the optional chaining operator nothing appears and console.log(response.value) shows null. If I remove it the console shows:
`{}` for 'Copy Object' but 'Copy Message' shows: `Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
my-component.vue:12` and expanding Proxy shows: `Proxy { <target>: {…}, <handler>: {…} }
​
<target>: Object { title: "Chapter 75", text: "Some long text here." }
​
<handler>: Object { get: get2(target, key, receiver), set: set2(target, key, value, receiver), deleteProperty: deleteProperty(target, key), … }
my-component.vue:12`

Comment: Ok. Try `const responseTitle = toRef(response, "title");`

Comment: That gives the same result as using `response.value?.title` and logging `toRef(response, "title")` shows `{
  "_object": {
    "__v_isShallow": false,
    "__v_isRef": true,
    "_rawValue": {
      "title": "Chapter 75",
      "text": "Some long text here."
    }
  },
  "_key": "title",
  "__v_isRef": true
}`

Comment: That starts throwing an error again, `TypeError: object is null`